# What does 「やりい」 mean?

Tags: words, spoken-language, imperatives

Here is the sentence including the word.

> たっぷりかわいがって**やりい**。

I guess it would mean 'to do' but I would like to know why it is written in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「やりい」 is a ***light or friendly imperative*** form of the Standard 「やれ（よ）/やりなさい（よ）/やりな（よ）」 used in parts of Western Japan.

「早{はや}く言{い}いなさい」⇒「はよ言い」

「食{た}べなさい」⇒「食べえ」

「よく見{み}なさい」⇒「よう見い」

Comment: I don't see dialectal features in OP's sentence. Are you sure it isn't Standard Japanese?

Comment: Wikipediaの[西日本方言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)の記事にこの用法があります。個人的にも西日本（大阪に限らず）な感じがします。

Comment: [ここのベストアンサー](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12128990377)によれば、時代劇で侍や姫様が「はよせい」と言うのも、西日本の命令形がベースになった古風な言い方、ということのようです。